# Compilation error in netty secure chat example from netty git repository

Tags: java, client, server, netty

I copied into my java project all the classes from the following netty example address:
https://github.com/netty/netty/tree/master/example/src/main/java/io/netty/example/securechat

and I added all the jars (without the jars that contain source code) from this file:
http://dl.bintray.com/netty/downloads/netty-4.0.27.Final.tar.bz2

However I have compilation errors in my classes because the SslContextBuilder class cannot be found inside the jars from the above address.

Would you tell me if i skipped a jar which contains the SslContextBuilder class or which is the right context to use the SslContextBuilder class in order to work the examples of code for the secure chat.

Best Regards,
Aurelian

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to run examples with 4.0.27.Final you need to ensure you use the examples which are part of the release tag.

So use these:

https://github.com/netty/netty/tree/netty-4.0.27.Final/example/src/main/java/io/netty/example

Comment: Thanks allot for your answer. It seems that this was my mistake. I will test and I will send you a feedback.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the examples for 5.0. Please try the examples at the branch 4.0 or 4.1, then it should work fine.  More specifically, try:

https://github.com/netty/netty/tree/4.0/example/src/main/java/io/netty/example/securechat

Comment: I tried the example for 4.0 branch and I have the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

It is fixed in 4.0.28.Final, I can find it in netty-handler-4.0.28.Final.jar.